# SQL Query Returning Deleted Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

I currently have the following table in my database, with the stated data in it:

**SUPPORT_USER_ROLES TABLE:**

```
USER_ID  |   ROLE_ID
1        |   1
1        |   2
2        |   2
*2*      |   *1*
```

The bottom row, notated by '*' has been deleted and in SQL Developer there is no sign of it.

I am now running the following query:

```
SELECT su.USER_ID
     , su.USERNAME
     , sur.ROLE_ID
     , sr.ROLE_NAME 
  FROM support_users su
     , support_users_roles sur
     , support_roles sr 
 WHERE su.USER_ID = sur.USER_ID 
   AND su.IS_ACTIVE != ‘N’ 
   AND sr.ROLE_ID = sur.ROLE_ID 
   AND sr.IS_ACTIVE != ‘N’
```

and it is returning the following:

```
{  (USER_ID : 1, ROLE_ID : 1),  
   (USER_ID : 1, ROLE_ID : 2), 
   (USER_ID : 2, ROLE_ID : 1),  
   (USER_ID : 2, ROLE_ID : 2)  }
```

as you can see, it is still giving me:

```
(USER_ID : 2, ROLE_ID : 1)
```

even though it doesn't exist anywhere anymore.

I am using Java, JSF, PrimeFaces, SQL Developer, Hibernate, Weblogic and Eclipse IDE. I'm not sure if I'm massively missing something here and need to refresh/update something somewhere.

I haven't had this before so I'm massively confused at the moment :S

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you did not provide complete information. you have 3 tables involved `support_users su, support_users_roles sur, support_roles`, but gave an example just of one. another point : your query returns 4 `su.USER_ID, su.USERNAME, sur.ROLE_ID, sr.ROLE_NAME`columns, but your _return_ shows just 2 `USER_ID , ROLE_ID `. so your exmples seems not be from the same one case. try to describe your problem more clear please with some proofs. because the only thing I am sure after reading: you got confused :-) and me too now :-)

Comment: How was it deleted? From Oracle SQL Developer? If yes then did you do a `commit` after delete? Make sure that `delete` is followed by `commit` on the same connection where you ran delete

Comment: You appear to have 'smart quotes' there!!!!

Comment: @Alex I've omitted all irrelevant information. Utsav, it was deleted using another SQL Statement, which is called using hibertnate in Eclipse in my program. Strawberry, what are 'smart quotes'? I'm assuming you mean the quotes surrounding N? This is just in this post don't worry, in my program they are as they should be.

Comment: if you know what is irrelevant and what is relevant, why do you ask for help?

Comment: @James - As I said, make sure to use `commit` from the same connection as your program from where you ran the `delete` statement. Deleting from application and commiting on SQL Developer wont work.

Comment: @Alex because I've looked and looked and can't figure out why it's not working as expected and thought a second pair of eyes/wisdom might know of something that I'm not doing. The other two tables just hold the Users and their IDs and Usernames and the Roles table just holds their IDs and Names.

Comment: @Utsav thanks, do would I be correct in doing: 'DELETE FROM ...; COMMIT;' ? Do you know how I can fix this now as I already called the delete without the commit in the first instance?

Comment: I will try to be polite. but remove this query out from your post. and replace with just `SELECT * FROM SUPPORT_USER_ROLES` if all the rest is irrelevant. Or if you want to be polite and get help. try to add all information related. including probably your java code.

Comment: @James - Yes you can do `delete from ...; commit;` And now you can either change your code to just `commit` or run the same `delete...; commit;` together. As the row is already deleted, it wont be deleted again but `commit` would happen.

Comment: @Alex sorry, I think we've misunderstood each other here. I meant irrelevant as in I didn't think it was needed here to aid with the question, not irrelevant as in I didn't need this data. I am restricted to what information I can post here, so have to keep it to a bare minimum. Although, I do understand providing as much information as possible to aid the people answering the question.

Comment: minimum is `SELECT * FROM SUPPORT_USER_ROLES`. if you post query with 3 tables involved, you should post all 3 tables schema and data sample. if you query returns 4 columns - provide all data returned by query. if you do transformation of returned data in your java code - post your java code. if you have any restrictions - SO is not the place where mentalists live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting comment as answer after knowing the issue

Please make sure to use `commit` from the same connection as your program from where you ran the `delete` statement. Deleting from application and commiting on SQL Developer will not work.

Right now you can do one of two things

(1) Change your code and just run `commit` once and then make sure to use `commit` after every `DML statement`.

(2) Use the `delete` and `commit` together. If the data is already `deleted`, it wont be deleted again and `commit` will happen after that. If it is not deleted, then if would be deleted and committed.

Comment: Thanks - all working now! Wouldn't let me append the commit onto my query as it was flagging ';' as an invaldi character (I'm using Hibernate). So I just made a separate query which just calls commit which I can repeatably use as and when I need :)

Answer (score 1):

James, if the row was deleted in SQL developer but not committed, it may show as not being there in the SQL developer interface, but is actually still present in the table until the delete command is explicitly committed.

This can be achieved by clicking the commit icon in SQL Developer or simply executing the following command: -

```
commit;
```

Comment: Before a commit in SQL Developer, the row still 'appears' but it is highlighted in some manor. The row does not appear anywhere. I actually deleted it from the database using an SQL Statement within my program code.